# React i18next using objects and map

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I want to know how can I translate data which is stored in objects, exported as separate file.

I have 2 components:

First is city component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { CityAttractions } from "../Data/CityAttractionsList";
import Attraction from "./Attraction";

const City = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="attractions-container">
        {CityAttractions.map((attraction, index) => (
          <Attraction attraction={attraction} key={index} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default City;
```

And second one is component of an attraction:

```
import React from "react";
const Attraction = ({ attraction }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <a href={attraction.url}>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h2>{attraction.title}</h2>
            <p>{attraction.description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="image">
          <img
            src={require(`../Images/Locations/City/${attraction.imageName}.jpg`)}
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Attraction;
```

My file with attraction data looks like this:

```
export const CityAttractions = [
    {
        title: "OLD CITY",
        description: 'Description number 1',
        imageName: "image_something_idk",
        url: "https://visitme.com",
    },
...
]
```

I can't find a way to translate this data so that it works...
If I put `const { t } = useTranslation();` in CityAttractions it says that React Hook "useTranslation" cannot be called at the top level.

Other translated words are saved in JSON files in locales, for example

```
// english JSON
{
  "welcome_to_react": "Welcome to React and react-i18next",
  "reserve_now": "Reserve now",
}
```

and

```
// croatian JSON
{
  "welcome_to_react": "Dobrodosli u React and react-i18next",
  "reserve_now": "Rezerviraj odmah",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a way:

First add JSON translations:

```
// english JSON
{
  "example_desc": "The old town - a castle from the 13th century on a hill with a beautiful view of the town."

}
```

and

```
// croatian JSON
{
  "example_desc": "Stari grad - dvorac iz 13. stoljeća na brijegu s kojeg se pruža prekrasan pogled na grad."
}
```

Then in data file remove text and set it to string of the string variable from JSON file:

```
export const CityAttractions = [
    {
        title: "OLD CITY",
        description: 'example_desc', // THIS
        imageName: "dubovac",
        url: "https://visitme.com",
    },
```

And the last step is to add `t` in attraction component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next"; // NEW

const Attraction = ({ attraction }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation(); // NEW
  return (
    <div>
      <a href={attraction.url}>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h2>{attraction.title}</h2>
            <p>{t(`${attraction.description}`)}</p> // NEW
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="image">
          <img
            src={require(`../Images/Locations/City/${attraction.imageName}.jpg`)}
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Attraction;
```